# How to get textfield that updates from listener in Java Swing for Hangman game?

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield

I am trying to write a code from Hangman program. I am not sure if this idea is correct. I was thinking of having dashes (_ _ _ _ _) in textfield which must dynamically change when user presses buttons. for example, if the user presses button "A" in the below code, the the dashes should change to ( A _ _ _ _ ). That is the user has guessed the letter A correct.

I am still confused as how to implement this. Attaching eventListeners would be my next part.
But for now, I have to get the basic GUI working, for which I need to an idea as how to implement entire thing.

what is the better way to get this working?
here is my code as of now.

```
import javax.swing.*;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;

public class HangmanGUI {

public HangmanGUI() {
    JFrame myframe= new JFrame();
    myframe.getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    JPanel myPanel = new JPanel();
    myPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(2,15));
    myframe.setSize(600,600);

    for (char alphabet = 'A';alphabet<='Z';alphabet++){
        myPanel.add(new JButton(alphabet+""));
    }

    myframe.getContentPane().add(myPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    myframe.setTitle("Hangman Game");
    myframe.setVisible(true);
    myframe.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    myframe.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
}

public static void main(String[] args){
    new HangmanGUI();
}
}
```

Comment: @camickr: I will accept the one I feel is good. that would take time to digest different solutions. so I will do it..

Comment: What do you mean you need to take time to digest the solutions? Your code is using a GridLayout which was suggested over 4 hours ago. How much more time do you need. Also you as still using setSize on the frame. That is not the way to create a GUI. You add your buttons to the panel and then pack() the frame. If the buttons are too small then maybe you use a bigger Font or maybe you increase the margin of the button to give it more space. There is rarely a good reason to hardcode the size of a frame. This is not one of them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes use [`JFromattedTextFeild`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFormattedTextField.html) with a [`MaskFormatter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/MaskFormatter.html) class. `MaskFormatter` has a `setPlaceholderCharacter('_')` function to help you with. You may also need to use the [`InputVerifier`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/InputVerifier.html) to verify user input's validity.  JFormattedTextFeild's documentation has example to show how to use an `InputVerifier` with it.

Comment: I am reading the docs for MasKformatter class. not sure if this is widely used class or is there some simple way to do it. Thanks for pointing it though..

Comment: I have given the link in my answer. put your pointer click on them. Google it to find it's tutorial page and try the tutorials. One by one. you will be able to do it, i know :)

Comment: @alterfox, it would not hurt to mention it. I have used it generally with `JFormattedTextFeild` many times.

Comment: @Sage: I have this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19458286/how-to-insert-characters-at-particular-index-in-jformattedfield-of-maskformatter. It appears that choosing MaskFormatter is not a good option.

Comment: @user1988876, your linked question has different use case. Read the OP's question more carefully/

Answer (score 4):

You could make use of the `DocumentFilter` API which would allow you to filter the incoming results from the user in real time.

This example is a little tricky, in that it hides the caret, so that it will allow the text to  appear in any order you want.

For example, the example uses `Duck` as the secret (the algorithm is case insensitive).  If the user types <kbd>c</kbd> then the field will appear as `__c_`.  Of course, you could just simply insert the incoming character in the what ever position was next, but where's the fun in that.

[image]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Point;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeListener;
import javax.swing.text.AbstractDocument;
import javax.swing.text.AttributeSet;
import javax.swing.text.BadLocationException;
import javax.swing.text.Caret;
import javax.swing.text.DefaultCaret;
import javax.swing.text.DocumentFilter;
import javax.swing.text.JTextComponent;

public class HangManField {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new HangManField();
    }

    public HangManField() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        private String secret = "Duck";
        private String guesses = secret;

        public TestPane() {

            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

            Caret blank = new DefaultCaret() {

                @Override
                public void paint(Graphics g) {
                }

                @Override
                public boolean isVisible() {
                    return false;
                }

                @Override
                public boolean isSelectionVisible() {
                    return false;
                }

            };

            JTextField field = new JTextField("____");
            field.setCaretPosition(0);
            field.setCaret(blank);
            ((AbstractDocument) field.getDocument()).setDocumentFilter(new DocumentFilter() {

                @Override
                public void insertString(DocumentFilter.FilterBypass fb, int offset, String string, AttributeSet attr) throws BadLocationException {

                    replace(fb, offset, offset, string, attr);

                }

                @Override
                public void replace(DocumentFilter.FilterBypass fb, int offset, int length, String text, AttributeSet attrs) throws BadLocationException {
                    System.out.println("rplace");
                    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(guesses.toLowerCase());
                    for (int index = 0; index < text.length(); index++) {
                        String at = text.substring(index, index + 1).toLowerCase();
                        int subIndex = sb.indexOf(at);
                        if (subIndex > -1) {
                            super.replace(fb, subIndex, 1, at, attrs);
                            sb.delete(index, index);
                        }
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void remove(DocumentFilter.FilterBypass fb, int offset, int length) throws BadLocationException {
                    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(length);
                    while (sb.length() < length) {
                        sb.append("_");
                    }
                    replace(fb, offset, length, sb.toString(), null);
                }
            });

            add(field);
        }
    }

}
```

Something this algorithm doesn't do, is currently support multiple, recurring characters, like `characters`.  It wouldn't take a lot for you to make this work though ;)

Comment: that was superfast to give the code.I will need time to understand as it uses API that I am not aware of...The graphics looks super cool..Thanks

Comment: Just remember, this implementation has some limitations, you can't "delete" a character for example, but I can't see you wanting to.  But it does allow you to do real time validation and display of the word (a little like the wheel of fortune style :P)

Comment: are these API used commonly? when I understand the code, I will see the limitation of why I cant delete a character. That could take me a while..

Comment: More or less, yes.  I use them alot when I want to restrict user input into a field.  It's generally a little more gritty than using something like `JFormattedTextField`, but provides a finer control of the validation process.  You can take a look at [this blog](http://www.jroller.com/dpmihai/entry/documentfilter) for examples

Comment: @MadProgrammer, It is a lots of work isn't it? For simple data processing why do you think this solution has better outcome than using `DefaultFormatterFactory` with a `Formatter` ? I like the `maskFormatter.setPlaceholderCharacter('_')` function which will achieve with single line of code.

Comment: @Sage It all comes down to what you want to do.  First, this provides real time feedback, that is, the user simple can't enter anything that is invalid (call me picky, but I'd prefer to restrict the user as they type then have to nag them after the fact ;)). This example can replace the character at the correct position - don't know if this is required or desired, but it's a neat feature.  It's just another approach to the problem ;).  I did a time field a while back that would filter invalid characters, but also invalid formats on the go ;)

Comment: @MadProgrammer, For validity check for fixed size input `MaskFormatter` serves it's purpose quite well. And `DefaultFormatter` with RegularExpression works for variable length data input for validity checking. They have Commit policy and `JFormattedTextField` creates Document Filter upon setting any `AbstractFormatter` to it. I am probably missing something. :( sorry

Comment: @Sage That's all true, assuming you can actually develop a regular expression that knows how to limit the input for the first two characters between `1` and `12` or only allow you to enter a value between 0-2 when the first character is a 1 (for example).  Sometimes, you just need to get your hands dirty.

Comment: @Sage My predecessor used this approach for date field entry.  Technically it works, but I can enter some wicked date values into the field before it's validated.  Call my picky, if I can get away with it, I like to add a little more control to the entry (date entry is impossible to do in real time, but you can stop a user from entering values of "40" in the date part, for example)

Comment: @sage The above example is also a little more fine tuned, in the fact that one, you can enter any of the valid characters you want, in any order and they will be "inserted" into their correct positions, a reg expression won't allow you to do that, it would expect that each character would need to be inserted in the correct order to begin with (based on what my simple example can do)

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't recommend text field with dashes, but you *can* do it like that. Give it a try, see how it looks and then create something better :-) You can, for example, use panels or labels with images, stylized buttons, or just large labels with a character each. Draw a picture of what you would like your game to look like, and then start coding. It's design before code :-)