# how to hide the insert caret in a JTextField?

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield

I'm making a calculator program with *Java* using *Java*'s *Swing* toolkit, and I want it to be similar to Windows' (default) calculator.

I have a `JTextField` for entering the numbers. You can see the cursor being displayed. I want to *hide* it.

[image]

I tried doing this:

```
textField.getCaret().setVisible(false);
```

but it didn't help. I also tried invoking it before and after I created and initialized the window but it still didn't work. The cursor was there.

I looked up the [JTextField](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextField.html) and [Caret](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/Caret.html) documentation but didn't find anything that could be useful for me, other than the `setVisible()` method which didn't work.

**How can I hide the insert caret/cursor?**

Comment: [This example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19392672/how-to-get-textfield-that-updates-from-listener-in-java-swing-for-hangman-game/19393048#19393048) use a custom "blank" caret to basically achieve the result you're looking for

Comment: @MadProgrammer It worked, thank you!

Comment: Not sure if it's the best solution, so might be interesting to see if anybody else has some ideas, but glad it could help in the short term

Comment: @MadProgrammer unless there's a method for either JTextField or Caret that hides it - like textField.hideCaret(); or something like that - I'm satisfied with your solution. But you're right, lets see if someone comes up with something even better.

Comment: In the example @MadProgrammer linked all it does is forces false on both visible and selectionVisible. So you could Always just try and do 
  Caret caret = textField.getCaret();
  caret.setSelectionVisible(false);
  caret.setVisible(false);

Answer (score 3):

you could just make it invisible,
you can try

```
textField.setCaretColor(Color.WHITE);
```

Comment: That would work, but if for some reason I decide to change the textfield color I'd have to change this line as well. For that reason the "answer" I got in the comments above works better in my opinion.

Comment: Then construct a color (variable) and make sure that any change will be inherited to both JTextField Background and Caret.